# Why won't Sequelize/Tedious connect to a localhost database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, reactjs, sequelize.js

I've been building a NodeJS/React app which connects to an MS SQL Server database. It was working fine, I uploaded it to the Windows hosting and it was working fine connecting to the dev database on a third party hosting company using this config file.

```js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const config = {
    user: "myusername",
    password: "mypassword",
    server: "database_server",
    database: "mydatabase",
    options: {
        enableArithAbort: true
    },
};

const seqInstance = new Sequelize(
    //
    config.database,
    config.user,
    config.password,
    {
        dialect: "mssql",
        host: config.server,
        dialectOptions: {
            encrypt: true,
            options: {
                validateBulkLoadParameters: true
            }
        },
    }
);


module.exports = { seqInstance };
```

But when I try to connect to the production database which is on the same server, localhost, using this change to the config -

```js
const config = {
    user: "mynewusername",
    password: "mynewpassword",
    server: "localhost",
    database: "myproductiondatabase",
    options: {
        enableArithAbort: true
    },
};
```

it refuses to connect and throws this error.
[image]

There are other app on the server connecting to that localhost sql server databases. Why is this small change not working?

Comment: Maybe SQL Server isn't configured to listen on `localhost [127.0.0.1]`?

Comment: There are other apps on that server using that SQL Server instance.

Comment: SQL Server can be configured to listen on specific IP addresses that don't include localhost. That seems to be what's happening here since your first example, not using localhost, connected. You can see which addresses and ports are enabled to listen via in SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for (Your Instance Name) > TCP/IP > Properties.